# MS Word VBA: Controlling excel workbook from word - Object required error

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm creating a MACRO in MS Word that needs to be able to (basically) copy and paste the contents of a table in word into excel.

DISCLAIMER: This might seem like an over complication; however, the approach is required as it is a setup for more complicated processing.

Long story short, I loop through every table in the document, and then every cell in the table and place the text into a corresponding cell in an excel sheet.

I have these declarations for excel objects:

```
'Objects
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
```

At the bottom of my loops, I have the following code:

```
xlBook.Worksheets(x).Activate
Set xlRange = xlBook.ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(65 + x) & y)
xlRange.Text = tString
```

The last line is throwing an "object required" error. The variable tstring is defined as a string and is set earlier in the loop.

The full code:

```
Sub CopyTablesToExcel()
    'Constants
    Const COLUMN_INDEX = 1
    Const ROW_INDEX = 2

    'Ints
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer 'Counters
    Dim numTables As Integer 'Number of tables in the word file
    Dim numSheets As Integer 'Number of sheets in the excel file
    Dim LastCell(1 To 2) As Integer   'Used to keep track of the last cell of a newly created excel table
    Dim map() As Integer 'Holds a map of the table columns

    'strings
    Dim xlBookName As String 'Name of the excel workbook
    Dim tString As String 'Temporary string

    'Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlRange As Excel.Range

    'Initialize
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    numSheets = xlBook.Worksheets.count
    numTables = ActiveDocument.Tables.count

    'Save the new book
    xlBookName = InputBox("Enter the ticker symbol:")
    xlBook.SaveAs FileName:=xlBookName

    'Show the file?
    xlApp.Visible = True

    'Make sure there are enough sheets
    If numSheets < numTables Then
        For x = 1 To (numTables - numSheets)
            xlBook.Worksheets.Add
            numSheets = numSheets + 1
        Next
    End If

    'Cycle through every table in the document and paste it to the worksheet
    For z = 1 To numTables 'Cycle through tables
        'Keep track of the last cell in the table
        LastCell(COLUMN_INDEX) = ActiveDocument.Tables(z).Columns.count
        LastCell(ROW_INDEX) = ActiveDocument.Tables(z).rows.count

        For x = ActiveDocument.Tables(z).rows(ActiveDocument.Tables(z).rows.count).Cells.count To 1 Step -1 'Cycle through columns
            'Used selections to support horizontally merged cells
            ActiveDocument.Tables(z).rows(ActiveDocument.Tables(z).rows.count).Cells(x).Select
            Selection.SelectColumn
            For y = Selection.Cells.count To 1 Step -1 'Cycle through cells
                tString = Selection.Cells(y).Range.Text

                'Move the content into excel
                xlBook.Worksheets(x).Activate
                Set xlRange = xlBook.ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(65 + x) & y)
                Debug.Print Chr(65 + x) & y 'Prints as expected
                xlRange.Text = tString
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I believe this is happening because the MACRO is failing to set the xlRange correctly. The output from debug.print is correct and is the format of "A#".

EDIT:

```
If Not xlRange Is Nothing Then
    xlRange.Text = tString 'Still errors
End If
```

The above will evaluate to true but still throws the error at the marked line

Comment: That's the error for sure. I am working on explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things:

`.Text` is a read only property. I would expect an an "Unable to set the text property of range object" error on this line:

```
xlRange.Text = tString
```

Change to:

```
xlRange.Value = tString
```

Also, your range assignment is probably wrong.  I don't know why you are doing `CHR(65)` instead of simply "A", but the problem is this line:

```
Set xlRange = xlBook.ActiveSheet.Range(Chr(65 + x) & y)
```

Here you are **ADDING** `x` to `65`, and then the `Chr` function returns whatever result that is, which could raise an error.  A value of `x` that is greater than 25 will most likely raise an error becasue then `Chr(65 + x)` does not evaluate to a valid range address.

Since you clarify in the comments that you do intend to do this (e.g., "A" + 1 = "B", etc.), it would be better probably to do this, if for no other reason than it seems more legible and leverages the Excel object model in a less-ambiguous manner:

```
Set xlRange = xlBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & y).Offset(,x)
```

Comment: I had already updated it to 64 when I realized that +1 would always be "B". Our max will never be over 17 so that wont be an issue but thanks for the warning. Using value updated the value of only 1 cell but I betting that's my fault. I just didn't realize that excel didn't like the .text property. Thanks

Comment: OK, then you were intending to *add* the integers in the `chr` function. I'll revise with another suggestion but glad this helped you !

Comment: That's good info. I'm used to c++ where we try to do as much work in the form of math as possible. Correct me if I'm wrong but it's typically much easier for a computer to do math and it has far less overhead. Is my solution not more technically efficient in VBA?

Comment: It may be  more efficient (I really don't know whether it is or not) but I have never seen that sort of convention used in VBA to define a range before. It would be my preference *not* to use that way of reference because it is not common (and hence not very easily interpreted by most humans I think) but also because it is very limited in what you can do with it -- you could not for instance easily refer to range "AG6" with that method unless you were to add more logic/etc.

Comment: I see your point. I'd like to as one more question: do I need to use a string or can I use x/y type coordinates (assuming top left is 0,0)?

Comment: You can use coordinates, e.g., `Range(Cells(1,1).Address)` would refer to cell `A1`.

Comment: Thanks David. This has really helped.